# Angular2 unable to display json response

Tags: json, angular

In a angular 2 template, I am unable to display data from json response:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "id": 5,
    "user_id": 1,
    "category_id": 1,
    "title": "ghfjhgf",
    "body": "jhgfjhgf",
    "created": "2017-01-19T18:22:02+00:00",
    "modified": "2017-01-19T18:22:02+00:00",
    "file": null,
    "column_9": null,
    "category": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Running",
      "body": "Regroupe toutes les traces relative à la course à pied."
    },
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "user@local.ch",
      "username": "user",
      "role": "user",
      "active": true,
      "created": "2017-01-15T16:21:44+00:00",
      "modified": "2017-01-15T16:21:44+00:00"
    }
  }
}
```

When I try with `track.success` there is no problem, it displays true, but when I try to display the id of data with any of the following:

```
track.data.id
track['data'].id
track['data']['id']
```

I have an undefined property. I need help please. Thanks in advance.

This is the output of {{ track | json }}

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "id": 6,
    "user_id": 1,
    "category_id": 1,
    "title": "dsfasd",
    "body": "afdasf",
    "created": "2017-01-19T18:27:26+00:00",
    "modified": "2017-01-19T18:27:26+00:00",
    "file": null,
    "column_9": null,
    "category": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Running",
      "body": "Regroupe toutes les traces relative à la course à pied."
    },
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "user@local.ch",
      "username": "user",
      "role": "user",
      "active": true,
      "created": "2017-01-15T16:21:44+00:00",
      "modified": "2017-01-15T16:21:44+00:00"
    }
  }
```

This is my service:

```
view(id):Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('http://cake/api/tracks/' + id + '.json')
            .map(response => response.json());
    }
```

My component:

```
ngOnInit() {

        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            this.id = +params['id'];
        })
        this.trackService.view(this.id).subscribe(track => this.track = track);
    }
```

Comment: do `<pre>{{track | json}}</pre>` on the ui and paste what it returns

Comment: Probably your `track` holds refference to the old object but your JSON was populated into a new one. Check the logic. `track = myJson; myJson = newJson` and your track will be out of sync

Comment: @VSO Thank's for your answers, I edited my post with the output.

Comment: @quepasso Thanks for the update. Are you sure the data is available when you are trying to log it? If you do <pre>{{track.data | json}}</pre> does that return? If it does, then I am guessing your problem is something to do with async. Is your data coming back to an Observable (or a promise)? if so, are you trying to get it from the next callback or then function? Please also post the code snippet where you are trying to use data.id in javascript/typescript.

Comment: @VSO Thank you for spending time answering me.

Comment: @v-andrew Thank you for spending time answering me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Safe Navigation(Elvis) operator when you wanted to display internal property of Object

```
track['data']?.id
track?.data?.id
```

Or use json pipe to display all data in json format.

```
track?.data | json
track | json
```

Comment: It work fine with track['data']?.id and track?.data?.id. Thank you!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @PankajParkar Can you elaborate please? I thought `?` was for when data may not be available? Obviously your answer is right if it worked, but how did you come to it? Upvoting.

Comment: Sure I'd like to explain it, but now I'm on bed, can't type much. So better go through [this docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html) link, let me know if you still don't understand. Would love to add explaination in anser, thanks ;)

Comment: @PankajParkar I understand the docs and just re-read them - I don't see why it solved the problem in this case - the object he is posting DOES have an id value, so how did this help? Anyway, I will ask a question later.

Comment: I got your point what you're saying... May be what OP has done is intially he had `track={}` so then when he did `{{track.success}}` it haven't got failed when intial chamge detection run and got true value displayed when object gort fills in.